# How to store file locally to a class?

Tags: python, file, class, python-2.7, csv

I have a class that is supposed to be able to read data from `.csv` files. In the `__init__` of the class I read the file and store it locally to the class as `self.csv_table`. The problem is that when I try to access this variable in another function I get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. How can I avoid this error and instead print the file?

---

```
import csv


class CsvFile(object):
    """
    A class that allows the user to read data from a csv file. Can read columns, rows, specific fields
    """
    def __init__(self, file, delimiter="'", quotechar='"'):
        """
        file: A string. The full path to the file and the file. /home/user/Documents/table.csv
        delimter & quotechar: Strings that define how the table's rows and columns are constructed
        return: the file in a way use-able to other functions
        Initializes the csv file
        """
        with open(file, 'r') as csv_file:
            self.csv_table = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar)  # local copy of csv file

    def read_csv(self):
        """
        Prints the csv file in a simple manner. Not much can be done with this.
        """
        for row in self.csv_table:
            print(', '.join(row))

my_file = CsvFile(file)
my_file.read_csv()  # this one causes an I/O error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, your problem is that self.csv_table contains the file reference itself, not the file content. Once you're out of the "with" statement, the file is closed, and you can no longer access it.

Since you care about the content, you need to store your content in the csv_table by iterating the csv_reader, for instance in your __init__ function, you can do something like this:

```
def __init__(self, file, delimiter="'", quotechar='"'):
    """
    file: A string. The full path to the file and the file. /home/user/Documents/table.csv
    delimter & quotechar: Strings that define how the table's rows and columns are constructed
    return: the file in a way use-able to other functions
    Initializes the csv file
    """
    self.csv_table = []
    with open(file, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar)  # local copy of csv file
        for data_entry in csv_reader:
            self.csv_table.append(data_entry)
```

Then you'll be able to access the content in self.csv_table as a list of list.

Or, if you really care about the file, you need to reopen it, anytime you want to access it =>
Change your self.csv_table by self.csv_filename, and in your read_csv function, you just reopen the file and create the reader anytime you need =>

```
import csv


class CsvFile(object):
    """
    A class that allows the user to read data from a csv file. Can read columns, rows, specific fields
    """
    def __init__(self, filename, delimiter="'", quotechar='"'):
        """
        filename: A string. The full path to the file and the file. /home/user/Documents/table.csv
        delimter & quotechar: Strings that define how the table's rows and columns are constructed
        return: the file in a way use-able to other functions
        Initializes the csv file
        """
        self.filename = filename
        self.delimiter = delimiter
        self.quotechar = quotechar

    def read_csv(self):
        """
        Prints the csv file in a simple manner. Not much can be done with this.
        """
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_table = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=self.delimiter, quotechar=self.quotechar)  
            for row in csv_table:
                print(', '.join(row))

my_file = CsvFile(file)
my_file.read_csv()  # this one causes an I/O error
```